# Awk: get a few fields with the delimiters in between as a string

Tags: awk

I'm curious if it is possible to retrieve not only the isolated fields using awk, but also a part of the original string that contains multiple adjacent fields and the enclosed delimiters?

For example, when using awk on

```
foo.bar.baz.test
```

with the `'.'` delimiter, and telling awk to extract the fields 2 and 3, I want to be able to retrieve

```
bar.baz
```

automatically. I know I can re-construct the part of the string later by hand, but that just does not feel right.

Ideas?

Comment: do you mean that you feel this `$2 OFS $3` not right? you are looking for an awk build-in function/whatever to achieve it?

Comment: Well, I don't even know yet what $2 OFS $3 means :) That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very sure if this is what you want :

```
kent$  echo "foo.bar.baz.test"|awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{print $2,$3}'
bar.baz
```

**EDIT**

> I need to generalize it to an unknown number of fields (no hardcoding
>   $2,$3, but everything starting with say $2 till the end - is that
>   possible?)

see the test below:

```
kent$  echo "a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.j.foo.bar"|awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)s=i==NF?s $i:s $i OFS;print s}'
b.c.d.e.f.g.h.j.foo.bar
```

Comment: OK, so I need to learn about this OFS construct. Thank you for the tip!
Also, I need to generalize it to an unknown number of fields (no hardcoding $2,$3, but everything starting with say $2 till the end - is that possible?)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
echo foo.bar.baz.test | awk -F. -vOFS=. '{print $2,$3}'
bar.baz
```

The `,` in the print command is shorthand for the output field separator(OFS).

Comment: Do you have a typo there? -vOFS=. a missing space maybe?